# Value of dimension data is scribbled with Regex Table values

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, custom-dimensions

I have a Regex table to identify classifications for different pages.
It works fine but the output value is somewhat scribbeled.

There might be character or two prepended or appended in the final Regex Table output value.
If the page is identified as My Class One (assigned output value) then the final value is something like dMy Class Onexz.

Regex table consists of piped values like asdsd|zxcz|zxzc and output field has readable value such as My Class One.

The final data is now a bit of a mess due these extra characters. Why is this happening? What to do?

EDIT: I don't know that what value a image brings since it has the same information as described here.
[image]

Comment: Any chance for an actual screenshot of your variable configuration?

Comment: @EikePierstorff added